# using tar to compress log directory, what happens when apache tries to write during compression?

Tags: linux, apache, logging, ubuntu, tar

I want to run a cron and compress my /var/log directory every hour to a tar file.. so I can backup that file.

What would happen to the log files the exact moment I run the tar command, will I miss those log lines or would the different softwares running and using /var/log wait, or will the tar be corrupt etc?

I have a busy webserver so it writes to the log files many times every second.

I plan on running

```
tar -zcf /home/user/file_date.tar /var/log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tar will have an incomplete version of the file, without the new data that was written while it compressed and you'll get the following message:

```
Truncated write; file may have grown while being archived.
```

You can test this with the following one liner:

```
perl -e 'open my $log_fh, ">", "/tmp/dir/log" or die; while (1) { print $log_fh $x++,"\n"; } '
```

and run

```
tar cvzf dir.tar.gz /tmp/dir/
```

from another terminal

I'd suggest renaming the file before tarring, or using `logrotate` if it fits your needs.